# echo an upload as an image

Tags: php, echo

So I have this echo:

```
echo './uploads/designments/' . $item['designment_id'] . '/thumbs/80x80';
```

Now in the div it shows it as a text line like  `product./uploads/designments/72/thumbs/80x80`

How can I show this thumb in the div?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply it to an `<img />` tag:

```
echo '<img src="./uploads/designments/' . $item['designment_id'] . '/thumbs/80x80"  alt="your image" />';
```

<sup>*Note: This is assuming that the image link supplied is actually the image.*</sup>

Comment: I think the link isnt correct but now it shows the standard broken image icon. Do you see a weird thing in my link?

Comment: Can you go to your link directly and see an image or not?

Comment: Oke this is what is shows in the elements: <img src="./uploads/designments/72/thumbs/80x80/"> But the upload path for one designment is this one /uploads/designments/71/thumbs/80x80/calculator_wheat_0.jpg do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Yes If I go to the uploads in the ftp and go to an image it will load it

Comment: I think the code doesn't provide the image name but only the id

Comment: You'll need to figure out how to get the `calculator_wheat_0.jpg` (image name) from your site somehow. It's beyond the scope of this question. What you generate is the path, not the full image.

Comment: You know how I can generate that?

Answer (score 0):

The printf is your friend and put the path into a img tag.

```
<?php 
    printf('<img src="./uploads/designments/%s/thumbs/80x80">',$item['designment_id']);
?>
```

Where `%s` is your data in `$item['designment_id']`

Comment: Oke this is hat is shows in the elements: <img src="./uploads/designments/72/thumbs/80x80/"> But the upload path for one designment is this one /uploads/designments/71/thumbs/80x80/calculator_wheat_0.jpg  do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: I think the code doesn't provide the image name but only the id

Comment: You have to remember that in ./uploads/designments/72/thumbs/80x80/72/thumbs/80x80 is the path where you have saved you img. The '<img>' tag in the src attributte will find your file and put it into your html code for see it. For example, if you have into your project an img like mypic.png, you have in php to find it like src="mypic.png" So, if all your images are stored in a folder, you have to access to him writing the path like (just if you have into your project folder another folder with all your images) src="images/mypic.png"

Comment: Oke so this is the correct URL in the ftp for a designment:  /uploads/designments/71/thumbs/80x80/calculator_wheat_0.jpg
But if I look in elements on the site it  will show the broken image icon with this URL:  /uploads/designments/72/thumbs/80x80    So I think I have to put something in the code to get the corresponding name of the file. Do you know what to put there? something like $file['name'] ??

Comment: The problem is that you are having errors routes. Remember that if the src attribute of the img tag will take charge of fetching your image and put it into your HTML code. That's why each route must end as .png, .jpg or any image format for it to take effect. If you're not putting the original route with their proper endings, you never will achieve that images are displayed properly.

Comment: I understand that. But what have to put I in the code to get the corresponding file names after /uploads/designments/72/thumbs/80x80/(filename.jpg)  ??